# Which handheld console performs better with larger game ports?

Tags: nintendo-switch, performance, steam-deck

I own the Nintendo Switch and am quite happy with its format when it comes to travelling and playing on the go, but the hardware sure has its limitations and struggles with bigger games, especially with the graphics.

Does the Steamdeck perform better with game ports like The Witcher Wild Hunt, No Man's Sky, Civilization compared to the Switch?

Or does the Steam deck use genuinely PC versions of games and runs it on a downscaled version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find videos directly comparing the Switch to Steam Deck for some titles, including [Witcher](https://youtu.be/HpIwB7jLwxs).

The steam deck has more impressive/modern hardware, so all things being equal, it will perform better.

All things are not always equal, however, so it will depend on the game.  As an example, No Man's Sky doesn't support multiplayer on the Switch, which for many will be a big factor if they owned both consoles and were trying to decide which version to buy.

The Steam deck will run either the Linux version of software or will run the Windows version via Proton.  Proton games vary in how they perform, so, again, it may vary by the game which version will perform better.